# Attaching a referencable .CSV file to a template project in Visual Studio

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2013

I was wondering how I would go about doing this.

Normally I don't worry about this because I just stick the CSV file in the Debug Folder and reference it using:

```
filePath = Application.StartupPath + "\\blah.csv";
```

But I want do to this a bit differently now because I want to create a good baseline template project that contains this CSV file whenever I make a new project from the template.

But I still want the file path to be relative, IE) I don't want to have to edit the path to that CSV for each new project that I make.

Does anyone know how to set this up?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand what you are needing you could go about it like this.

```
string appPath;
appPath = System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetName().CodeBase);
appPath = appPath.Replace("file:\\", "");
appPath = appPath + @"\" + "filename.csv";
```

Comment: Please remember to use code blocks for your code snippets.

Comment: That's pretty much doing exactly what my code does.

Comment: but I don't want to have to manually drop the CSV file into the debug folder each time I start a new project from the template

Comment: Where is the file going to reside? If it's going to be in a specific spot, cant you just directly hard code the path?

Comment: When I start a new project from the template the path is going to change to the new projects folder.

Comment: So what you are saying is you want to create the new project from the template but the .csv is going to stay in the original project and you don't want to have to move a copy of the .csv into the new debug folder. Correct? If so just hard code the path of the .csv to exactly where your original project resides. Would that not work?

Comment: The CSV should be copied into the new project, because the idea is each project will have its own CSV, where other developers will enter their own data, on their own computers. I just want to provide them with a VS template to give them starting code.

Comment: Forgive me if I am not understanding, but if you are just copying the project over, then I do not understand why the above code would not work. I have a project like that, that I have copied many times into different directories, and the above code references the file of the project no matter where the project is.